# Залить локальные коммиты в отдельную ветку

Tags: git, github

Завел на `github` репозиторий, который долгое время оставался с одной веткой `master`. В какой то момент создал новую, там же на гитхабе :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

далее слил её локально в новую папку с помощью

> > git clone --branch serverBranchName https://github.com/username/reponame/

После внесения изменений, в следующем порядке приступил к пушу :

> > git add .
> >
> > git commit -m "test msg"
> >
> > git add remote origin https://github.com/username/reponame/
> >
> > git checkout -b serverBranchName
> >
> > git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/serverBranchName serverBranchName
> >
> > git push origin/serverBranchName

На что получаю ошибку :

```
Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Все права у меня есть, подключаюсь по ssh и все равно не могу залить изменения в новую ветку. Имена удаленного и локальнго `brach` одинаковы. Кто сталкивался - подскажите в чем дело ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выполнения описанной Вами задачи достaточно, после создания Вами отдельной ветки *new_Branch* от ветки *master*:

1. git clone --branch new_Branch https://github.com/username/reponame/
2. внесение изменений
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "fix something ..."
5. git push
6. profit ;)

---

Команды, цель которых для меня непонятны, в контексте вашей задачи:

- `git clone --branch new_Branch https://github.com/username/reponame/` - Вам должна была вернуться ошибка. т.к. вы ранее создали ветку *new_Branch*, а указываете *p2p_chat_open*
- `git remote add origin https://github.com/username/reponame/`  - origin уже установлен таким после команды клонирования. Лишнее.
- `git checkout -b serverBranchName` - создаете еще одну ветку *serverBranchName* от текущей и переключаетесь на нее.
- <strike>`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/serverBranchName serverBranchName` - текущую ветку *serverBranchName* указываете отслеживаемой и связываете ее с одноименной на удаленном сервере.</strike>
- `git push origin/serverBranchName` - пушите текущую ветку *serverBranchName* на удаленный сервер в ветку *origin/serverBranchName*, но у вас **нет такой ветки** на удаленном сервере и в ответ вы получаете ошибку.

Comment: git remote -v показывает что origin отсутствует. поэтому и добавляю

Comment: после добавления origin ошибка - `Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not have locally.`

Comment: попробуйте вытянуть с удаленного сервера правки (которых у вас нет локально) перед тем как туда пушить свои